# How to become a expert in electronics circuit design in embedded product development?

Tags: circuit-analysis, embedded

I want to design electronics circuit for embedded product development. Currently I have a project where we have to design the ECU and BCM of automotive vehicle.

Comment: To become an expert in anything, one first needs to become a beginner, then intermediate and then expert. Between the steps one needs to learn and gain experience.

Comment: Becoming an expert typically comes from experience.  Successfully design lots of products of incrementally increasing complexity, learn from your mistakes, and over time you will be come and expert.

Comment: why did you say this? ... `Currently I have a project where we have to design the ECU and BCM of automotive vehicle` ... it seems irrelevant to the question in the title

Comment: Embedded product development is broad enough that you'll not likely be an expert in more than one or two fields at once. If  you're an expert in automotive, that's quite different from aerospace, industrial motion control systems, process controllers, or toys.

Answer (score 2):

To become an expert you have picked a very tough arena. To start you will need to have your degree in the appropriated field and get an experienced mentor. Find out what the standards are you will have to comply with, there are many such as ISO, SAE, AEQ and other standards. You will soon find out each OEM also has its own set of standards that do not necessarily agree with some of the others. This also includes Acronyms, they vary from OEM to OEM and sometimes between tiers. You need to understand FEMA, PPAP, 8D (7D) reports and many of the other requirements. You may need to know a little about NHTSA, CARB and many other government agencies. Working actively in in the field for about ten to twelve years minimum full time in different areas, this will get you close. You will need to experience several product launches.  I suggest you join SAE, and get involved in some of the 'projects' that are in the area you want to become familiar. It will also be helpful if you understand analog and its ramifications in a vehicle. You will learn more as you progress in your endeavor.
This information should get you started, as you evolve you will find this is an extremely short synopsis.